# Algorithm time complexity with binary search

Tags: time, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am trying to figure out what the time complexity of my algorithm is, I have algorithm with binary search, which is in general O(log n), I know. But I search between two constants, namely x=1 and x = 2^31 - 1 (size of integer). I think that in the worst case my time complexity is log2(2^31) = 31, so binary search takes 31 steps in the worst case. However every step in binary search I call a function, which has O(n) runtime (just one loop of the size of the input). Will my algorithm simply be of order O(31n)=O(n)?

The input of my algorithm: a key, two arrays a and b of size n.

In code it will look something like this:

```
    binarySearch(key, a, b)
    min = 0, max = 2^31 - 1
    mid = (min + max) / 2
    while (min<=max) { 
        x = function(mid, a, b); //this function has O(n)
        if (x==key) {
            return mid;
        } else if (x < key) { 
            min = mid + 1
        } else {
            max = mid - 1
        }
        mid = (min + max) / 2
    }
    return KEY_NOT_FOUND
```

I just want to be sure, please if you come with a time complexity (reduced ones) explain your answer.

Comment: If your list is sorted then yes it's O(n) but not necessarily 31n since you have to count everything for the constant.

Comment: there is no list, so nothing to sort. I am just checking of the output of the function is equal to a certain integer between 0 <= key <= 2^31 - 1 and for which input that is. I am not sure what you mean with the last part of your sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Yes, You are absolutely right.

In the worst case `function()` will be invoked 31 times, and each invocation requires time `O(n)`, hence the running time of your algorithm is simply given by `31 * O(n) = O(n)`.

**Solution for the original question where `x = function(mid)`**

Your question is a bit fishy, the time complexity of your algorithm should be `O(1)`.

One important point when we talk about the time complexity of an algorithm is that:

> We always consider the time that the algorithm requires **with respect to the size of it's input**.

In the following snippet:

```
x = function(mid); //this function has O(n)
```

While `function()` may be a linear time function, but in your case, `function()` only takes input (`mid`) from the set `{0, 1, ..., 230}`, so in the worst case `function()` computes in time  `max{T(0), T(1), ..., T(230)} = T`, which is a constant!

So in the worst case, your while loop will invoke `function()` 31 times, so in the worst case your algorithm runs in time `31 * T`, which is a constant.

Note that the input of your algorithm is `key`, and the worst case running time of your algorithm is `31 * T`, which is actually **independent** of the size of your input `key`! So the time complexity is `O(1)`.

In your case, I don't think talking about time complexity in terms of big-O notation is appropriate. I would suggest you to talk about the numbers of computation steps required in the worst case.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very clear, however you made me realize I made a mistake in the description, my size of the input is not 'key'. The size of my input are two arrays of integers of size n. So following your explanation I think I was right, correct? I will the change the description.

Comment: @Chantal You are absolutely right, the complexity in that case is `O(n)` for exactly the same reason you have stated in your question